# How to customize (redefine) the outliers (fliers) in a boxplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I have some set of data points that I have removed their outliers by myself before plotting them using pl.boxplot(). Now, after plotting them using this function, I can see some fliers in my plot. I do not want to remove the fliers but include them inside the boxes. How can I figure this out?

[image: Boxplots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to omit *showing* the outliers you can use the `showfliers` argument of `plt.boxplot`.

However, if I interpret your question correctly you wish to still show the fliers but have them contained within the whiskers of the boxplot? If so, this isn't possible under the standard interpretation of a boxplot.

Typically the lower bound of the box is defined at the 25th percentile (Q1). Similarly, the upper bound of the box is defined at the 75th percentile (Q3). The difference between these locations is defined as the inter-quartile range (IQR).

The upper and lower whiskers of the boxplot are then defined as Q3 + 1.5 * IQR and Q1 - 1.5 * IQR. Any points outside of the whiskers are classified as outliers. As such, outliers will *always* be outside of the box in a standard boxplot.

If you wish to have your 'outliers' included within the boxes you'll have to break the graphical conventions of the boxplot. One way you could do this is by changing the percentiles which define the upper and lower part of the box. If it's this that you want to achieve there's an [outline of how to do so here](https://jwalton.info/Matplotlib-custom-boxplots/). (Generally I wouldn't recommend breaking graphical convention, it can be very easy to mislead a reader)